# Texture paint - fill polygon with mouse click

Tags: texture-painting

I would like to single click-fill a polygon in texture paint mode, without selecting it first.

Is there any kind of script that does that, or is it possible to ad multiple commands to one mouse click, like select polygon - fill - deselect polygon .. with just one click.
thanks!

Comment: It's a bit tricky to do with code, I think it might just be easier to use a macro software that would do a SHIFT+CLIC to select face - > CLIC (using fill paint tool), and ALT+A to deselect in just one clic.

Comment: Thanks, will try that!